# How do I view data from database table according to a user condition?

Tags: android, sql

I would to like to display data from a local database table according to a user condition.

Code to display:

```
    public void viewContact(){
    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name").toString();
    tvName.setText(name);

    String phone = db.getContacts(name).toString();
    tvPhone.setText(phone);

    String web = db.getContacts(name.toString();
    tvWeb.setText(web);
}
```

DBHelper.class:

```
    public Cursor getContacts(String therapist_name){
    String selectQuery = " SELECT therapist_phone, therapist_web " +
            " FROM " + THERAPIST_TABLE + " WHERE " + THERA_NAME + " = " + "'" + therapist_name + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Explanation: 
The activity receives contact name from previous activity (hence getIntent()). Then with that, it would like to view data from database relating to the contact and thus would like to view the phone_number and website columns.

So if therapist_name is equal that of selected contact from previous activity, it would only display the therapist_number and therapist_website of that contact in the next activity.

Comment: Your  getContacts() returns cursor, you need to move to first row and get name and web from cursor, no need to call getContacts() twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an Object Contact with the properties you want, and everytime you run the query, go trough the steps [Ana said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875027/4499937) of checking if the cursor is null and moving to first (i personally check the size of the cursor also, to Log an error if is empty).

And then return the created object, so when you call the method, you have everything there, something like this:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts(String therapist_name){
    List<Contact> listOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = " SELECT therapist_phone, therapist_web " +
            " FROM " + THERAPIST_TABLE + " WHERE " + THERA_NAME + " = " + "'" + therapist_name + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        //Save data in variables here
        String ph_no = cursor.getString(0);  // therapist contact
        String web = cursor.getString(1);    //therapist web
        listOfContacts.add(new Contact(ph_no, web));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
    }
 return listOfContacts;
}
```

This returns a list of objects, just in case there is more than one match. You can tweak it to get one, or the first match, and return just the Contact object, so you would have your data,

Answer (score 0):

You are just returning cursor object. Read the data and then return the retrieved data.

Example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            //Save data in variables here
            ph_no = cursor.getString(0);  // therapist contact
            web = cursor.getString(1);    //therapist web
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
}
//pass an array of ph_no and web from here now
```